# Undo comboboxes - in groupbox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have multiple ComboBoxes which are databinded to DB. I use them on Form to edit records and I want to undo them with my Cancel button. I tried already with Dataset.RejectChanges, but that clears all ComboBoxes. What would be the easiest way to position them back to 1st selectedIndex - to undo them ?

Comment: Why does this question deserve minus votes - because there isn't any code provided ? I'm just asking how should I undo comboboxes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. When combobox is databinded you have to clear databind, fill dataset again and repeat databind. This solved my problem, but It also all other databinded controls gets undo this way.